# Use intent ACTION_SEND to sharing data from anchor link to specific app

Tags: android, android-intent, telegram

I want to share data from my website to Android app using a single link.
For example when user click on the below link:
`<a href="intent://SEND/#Intent;scheme=tg;package=org.telegram.messenger;S.EXTRA_TEXT='some text';end"> Share... </a>`
the browser launch Telegram app and ask user to select a contact to send EXTRA_TEXT to him/her. But the above code only open the telegram app and doesn't pass the EXTRA_TEXT to app.

I found this guide but this is JAVA and I don't know how to use this code in a link:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: It's just opening the telegram app and doesn't pass the EXTRA_TEXT to app.

Answer (score 0):

Put the data scheme and parameters in the anchor tag.
For e.g.:

> myappschema://?token=123

where it will send token to the myappschema.

In the AndroidManifest of your app; put this intent filter on your activity which you wish to open from web.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />
                <data android:scheme="myappschema" />
</intent-filter>
```

Inside your activity; you can fetch data from Intent.
eg: `Uri data =getIntent().getData();`

Comment: Thanks buddy! But I don't want to create an app. I just want to make a cool share button to share content from webpage to any android app (e.g. Telegram)

Comment: Then share intent is there for you man! Just use it with content you wish to share